# iOS Walkie Talkie app plays audio in background

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm working on a Walkie Talkie app and have the basics working. You select a user, record a message which is then sent via push notification. They open the app which downloads and plays the message. I was pretty happy with it until I came across [Zello](http://itunes.apple.com/app/zello-walkie-talkie/id508231856?ls=1&mt=8).

They are doing 2 things of interest:

1) If you receive a message and the app is running in the background it will display a notification and begin playing the message without having to open the app.

[image: Zello]

2) The message is streamed to your phone and begins playback while the other user is still speaking.

Can anyone give me a clue as to how they're doing this? I've added the basics like setting the audio/voip background mode keys and initializing the audio session:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```

But I'm unsure how to proceed beyond this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in viewdidload method:

```
    NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
    NSError *activationErr  = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryErr];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationErr];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier newTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    newTaskId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:NULL];
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the code sample. I tried this but its still not working. I'm beginning to think sockets are involved. I'll keep digging.

Comment: @marcdown are you able to solve the issue? In my case after receiving push notification I am able to connect socket and and then joined room and then webrtc stream is coming. But I can not hear the sound, because I am getting "AURemoteIO.cpp:1668  AUIOClient_StartIO failed (561145187)". I tried by setting only playback mode but none of them worked.