# Play Webrtc Audio message when IOS app is in background

Tags: ios, react-native, webrtc, react-native-push-notification, react-native-background-fetch

Hi this might be duplicate to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336781/ios-walkie-talkie-app-plays-audio-in-background). But I did not find right answer for this. I have developed an app like zello push to talk using react-native. I want to play the audio message automatically without any user interaction when the app is in background or killed. Whenever any user sending real time audio message, I am sending a push notification to ios app and after receiving notification I am invoking a function which establishes socket connection with the webrtc server and then join in the room in which webrtc audio broadcasting is happening. Now I checked that socket is connected and also joining in room successfully done after receiving push notification when app is in background. But there I could not hear any audio and received following error message.

```
AURemoteIO.cpp:1668  AUIOClient_StartIO failed (561145187)
```

Then I have set AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback and that error gone. But this time also did not hear any audio sound.
The app is working fine when it is in foreground. I am using react-native and this is happening for IOS app only. Any help is appreciated. In xcode I have enabled push-notifications, background-fetch, background-airplay etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your app **Capabilities Background Modes** (Audio and AirPlay).

To Enable this select your iOS project in iOS then go to **Signing & Capabilities** tab.

Check for Background Modes and select **Audio, AirPlay and Picture In Picture** option.
Also, set your `AVAudioSession` category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` and set it active.
Example:

```
do {
      try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)
      NSLog("Playback OK")
      try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
       NSLog("Session is Active")
     } catch {
       NSLog("ERROR: CANNOT PLAY MUSIC IN BACKGROUND. Message from code: \"\(error)\"")
  }
```

Comment: Daljeet as I mentioned in the question that I have already applied Audio, AirPlay and Picture in Picture at Background Modes and set the AVAudioSession to Playback. That time the above error is solved but I still could not hear any voice.

Comment: Did you also added this AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true) while setting playback

Comment: Yes I have set that to true. AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)